# Plotly Heatmap - Giving your header/index names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly

Following the tutorial at - https://plotly.com/python/heatmaps/

If you do the lines

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.medals_wide(indexed=True)
```

You can see that the "header" row is named "medals" allowing it to be used as an id later.  Similar for nations.

When I create my own pandas dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(model_data, columns=model_names, index=test_names)
```

What would I have to add to get the equivalent of "medals" and "nations" from the previous example into my dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

- assuming you have a 2D array / list of data
- as simple as building data frame in way you note

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

models = [f"model {n}" for n in range(4)]
tests = [f"test {n}" for n in range(10)]
px.imshow(pd.DataFrame(index=tests, data=np.random.uniform(1,3,(len(tests),len(models))), columns=models))
```